# Problema al enviar datos con $.ajax()

Tags: php, jquery

Gracias anticipadas a todos los que puedan ayudarme con esta duda.
Recién estoy empezando con JQUERY y estoy intentando realizar un form que debería hacer unos cálculos en base a datos que devuelva una db con una consulta en archivo externo en php.
En base a todo lo que he buscado y leído, tengo el siguiente archivo en PHP que realiza la consulta (La misma esta probada y devuelve datos). (turi.php)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Consulta a MySQL - turi.php]

Y este es el código jquery, que le pido se active al cambiar un select

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#destinos').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {filtro: "FsL", limit: 15},
          url: "turi.php",
          success : function(resp) {
            // Aquí debería poder recorrer el resultado que devuelve la consulta... creo :)
          },
          error : function(resp) {
            alert("Error");
          }

      })
})});
```

Para que me devuelva un objeto y poder recorrerlo. Y en base a otros datos que cargue el usuario me haga un cálculo.
[image: Formulario para se cálculo en base a la consulta]

Espero que sea claro.

Nuevamente Gracias

Comment: resp es tu respuesta y te lo trae como json, tu puedes iterar sobres resp y obtener sus elementos

Comment: entiendo que resp está referida a si se conectó o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado de los datos procesados por `php` es lo que te llega en el parámetro `resp` que estás pasando al evento `success` del `ajax`, para recorrer ese objeto `json` podrías usar el método `$.each()` de **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#destinos').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {filtro: "FsL", limit: 15},
            url: "turi.php",
            success : function(resp) {
                $.each(resp, function(index, dato){
                    console.log(dato.propiedad);
                });
            },
            error : function(resp) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**$.each()**

Éste método se usa para recorrer cualquier tipo de colección de datos (objeto o array), como puedes ver el primer parámetro es la colección que se quiere recorrer, y el segundo parámetro es un callback que se ejecuta por cada repetición realizada. Este callback recibe dos parámetros que son obligatorios:

`index`: es el índice/nombre

`dato`: es el objeto/valor

Realmente a estos dos parámetros puedes colocarle el nombre que quieras, lo importante es que estén los dos.

Espero haber sido claro, saludos !

Comment: Lo pongo tal cual me lo pasas y me sale el alert de "Error"

Comment: Si te ejecuta el evento error es por que desde php tienes errores, debes revisar que por ejm la consulta si te esté trayendo datos, yo colocaría la línea echo json_encode.... dentro del else de la condición

Comment: Gracias Camilo. La consulta esta probada desde otro código y me trae datos. Probé tu sugerencia y tampoco

Comment: Es extraño, error() solo se ejecuta por problemas de servidor, revisa el network ahí podrás ver el error exacto, también puedes cambiar alert("Error"); por console.log(resp) para ver que error te saca

Comment: El responsetext tira el siguiente error"<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: x in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\a-Json\turi.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\a-Json\turi.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\a-Json\turi.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\a-Json\turi.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
"

Comment: Bueno en tu foto no se alcanza a ver, simplemente te está diciendo que en php estas accediendo a algo que no le estas enviando en la línea 3

Comment: Sí Camilo, en el apuro seleccioné mal. ahora agregué lo que faltaba. Por lo que había buscado, la idea era que data llevaba los filtros para hacer la consulta. Por eso en la otra imagen recorro ese objeto  y lo ubico en cada parte del select

Comment: Pero en tu php debes recibirlos así: $_POST['filtro'] Y $_POST['limit'], no estoy seguro si solo con colocar data lleguen los valores enviados... te sigue saliendo algún error o algo en el network ?

Comment: Si, en base a tu pista vi eso.Pero parece que el problema ahora paso al lado del php. En la línea 4 ahora dice $obj = json_decode($_POST["filtro"],$_POST["limit"]); Pero el responseText ahora dice Trying to get property of non-object en la línea del Query

Comment: @SolucionesPyMESyHogares que error te sale ?

Comment: te contesté en ni comentario anterior, editado

Comment: @SolucionesPyMESyHogares ya no tienes que hacer json_decode, para que lo estas usando ? con $_POST["filtro"] y $_POST["limit"] ya obtienes los valores por separado y puedes agregarlos a tu consulta

Comment: Por lo que había leído creí que ese era el modo y porque pensé que lo que enviaba por $.ajax era un json que tenía que decodificar en PHP. Pero parece que no es así. Ahora Coloque cada POST en variables distintas, puse esas variables en el sql y me devuelve los objetos perfectamente. Si tuvieras algún material extra donde este más claro este tema entre php y jquery, el uso de .ajax() ó .post() te lo voy a agradecer. Googleando encontré poco y nada, como verás.

Comment: @SolucionesPyMESyHogares pues este [ejemplo paso a paso](https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso) me parece muy completo, me alegra que te haya funcionado, pudiste recorrer el objeto que te devuelve con el $.each() ?

Comment: Lástima que no pueda colocarlo aquí en el comentario. Pero si te referís a que me muestra en la consola 7 objetos uno debajo de otro que coinciden con la consulta, entonces sí. Dejé ese each tal cual lo colocaste. Ahora me faltaría analizar de donde sale ese index y ese dato. Anduve también por ese enlace que me enviaste. Voy a releerlo más detenidamente.

Comment: @SolucionesPyMESyHogares si te sale eso que dices en la consola entonces está correcto, ya solo falta acceder a las propiedades de cada objeto, te voy a explicar más de $.eachen una edición a la respuesta, ahora te invito a considerar marcar la respuesta como aceptada ya que solucionó tu problema inicial que era el recorrer el objeto que te devolvía el back-end, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

mas o menos deberia ser asi

reemplaza los nombres y listo

```html
$("#boton_que_envia_los_datos").click(function(){
var url = "documento.php";

$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#Id_de_tu_formulario").serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {                         
          $("#id_del_elemento_donde_recibiras_la_respuesta").html(data); 
        }
 });
}
```

en el HTML formulario que enviaras

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="Id_de_tu_formulario" method="post">

<input type='text' name='txt1'  id='txt1' >


 <button type="submit" id="boton_que_envia_los_datos" name="boton_que_envia_los_datos">Enviar</button>

</form>

<div id="id_del_elemento_donde_recibiras_la_respuesta"></div>
```

en el documento php que recibirás los datos

```html
<?php

print_r($_POST);



?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El problema es que los datos que están en el formulario no son lo que quiero utilizar para filtrar, lo digo por el serialize